# How to create a Javascript function that uses parameters and arguments to change the font size and color of an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, parameters, colors, arguments, font-size

I created a button that uses function fontColor to activate the id= "main header". I'm trying to get the parameters of function to accept arguments to adjust the font size and color in the id="Main Header". Can I get some help with this? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" onClick="fontColor(30,"blue");" id="push">Change.</button>
    <h1 id="Main Header"> HI</h1>
    <p id="this one">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>



function fontColor(s, c) {
    var size = element.style.fontsize(s);
    var color = element.style.color(c);
    var result = [size, color];
    document.getElementById("Main Header").innerHTML = result;

}
```

Comment: You should use single quotes inside of the onclick propery. Currently it only says `onClick="fontColor(30,"`. change it to `onClick="fontColor(30,'blue');`

Comment: what is `element`  ? I mean which element ?

Comment: You have invalid HTML, `id` cannot be setted with separeted words like `Main Header` or `this one`, use as `Main_Header`

Comment: Noted, I actually realized that space yesterday. However, it still works which surprised me.

Comment: Forgot about the double quotes and single quotes. I'm a beginner at JS, so i'm constantly making rookie mistakes lol. Thanks for that correction.

Answer (score 0):

Camel-case element.style.fontSize

I could be wrong but also I believe element.style.fontSize needs a string so fontColor("30px","blue")

EDIT: element is undefined and there's more errors than I previously thought. I couldn't just tell you how to fix the errors so I just rewrote your function.

A better solution would be:

```
function fontColor(s, c) {
  var element = document.getElementById("MainHeader"); <- should be one word
  element.style.fontSize = s;
  element.style.color = c;
```

}

Comment: abou camel-case, it's correct. ut the inline call to the `fontColor` function should be `onclick="fontColor('30px', 'blue')"`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Ive been having troubles with the concept of parameters and arguments. Think I'm getting closer now. This snipped of code was about the 10th different way I tried to write it lol. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the id to a variable, and change it from there. Also, as the other user said, `fontSize` should be suffixed with `px`

```
function fontColor(s, c) {
    var changing = document.getElementById("Main Header");
    changing.style.fontSize = s;
    changing.style.color = c;
}
```